# Can we re-open the door to something a little like photo critique?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, critiques

See [How can we do photo critiques?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/815/how-can-we-do-photo-critiques) and [Should Photo Critiques be allowed?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150/should-photo-critiques-be-allowed) for previous discussion. It's generally been the consensus in the past that this is outside the charter of the site.

But our main problem right now is *lack of questions*. And a good portion of the questions we get are "*16-92mm f/3.2 vs 14-87mm f/3.9 which to buy?*" — which I think we *also* really only tolerate because there's not much coming in. I'd much rather have the photo-critique questions than many more of those!

I'd like to open the door to more questions about *how to make a good photo*, and specifically *encourage* people to post examples as part of the question.

*Unlike* a photo critique, I think they *should* focus on a specific concern, rather than open "what do you think of my photo". I think [What is a point of interest in a photograph and where is it lacking in this candle picture?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20927/what-is-a-point-of-interest-in-a-photograph-and-where-is-it-lacking-in-this-cand) is a great example of this. More questions like this would be *great* for the site, and really help us grow.

Right now, the site already says that specific questions like this *are* allowed, but we've tended to interpret that as meaning specific *technical issues*. How can we expand that and make it not just allowed but encouraged?

Comment: So, just to be clear, you're suggesting that we encourage questions that focus on what specific creative thing can be fixed in a picture?

Comment: @rfusca: I mostly want to raise the discussion. I don't think we want people to post photos with wide-open "so, what do you think?" or even "does this work for you?" questions, but I _would_ like to see it go beyond asking for _fixes_ too.

Comment: Everybody knows that the 14-87 isn't worth much!  .... now seriously instead: +1 I agree with @mattdm.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My opinion is that the door was never closed, only guarded.

We do [allow critique, but it needs to focused.](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/818/67)

As a community, we have avoided questions that are general critique because it isn't a good fit for the Q&A system. A critique is necessarily subjective, and usually doesn't lend itself to really being *answered*.  However, if the focus is on a specific portion of the image it may certainly be possible to ask a question that is answerable.

Concerning the [example](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/20927/67):

This seems to be a good example of an on-topic critique question.  It has a specific purpose which isn't overtly subjective.

Comment: There's a new Graphic Design Critique proposal, could photo critiques go there perhaps?

Comment: @Zizouz212 Looks like that's no longer live, so I guess not :)

Answer (score 11):

My only problem is this:

When we encouraged critical comments on PotW entries it went badly...really, really bad.  Lost at least a few really good members badly.

When you start asking, generally, what is creatively wrong with a picture that somebody likes, we open the door for all sorts of stupid comments like "I don't think you should take pictures of cats" .

I'm fine with addressing the creative side, but I still think the question needs to address something specific the photog wants addressed.  If he comes in for composition help, he doesn't need to hear a criticism of his subject choice.

Comment: +1 for no pictures of cats

Comment: @dpollitt — sounds like [a challenge!](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/a/2046/1943) mwhahahah.

Comment: I don’t get it (and admittedly I wasn’t here when critique on POTW was encouraged).  My POTW got comments that *could* be viewed as critical. It seems to me that you’re blurring the responsibilities of the question asker and the answerer.  Specific questions are great, but people already do give opinion (sometimes off-topic) in their answers.  If it’s inappropriate they can be flagged/down voted/edited by the community which is what already happens on other questions.  Why are creative questions different?

Comment: @forsvarir Because there's a difference between something that is bad/offensive and the mods need to take care of, versus something that is just bad/stupid.  Voting can take care of it for sure, but I don't think we should set ourselves up for trouble.  Again, I'm not saying "no creative questions", but just that like all other questions on the site, there needs to be a focus for it.

Answer (score 7):

I think that sort of question ought to be welcome, particularly when it's in the form of:

> I received the following critique, and I can't figure out for the life of me what the heck they're talking about.

I mean, it's nice to talk in abstractions about compositional "rules", lighting ratios, "correct" exposure, and so forth, but it can be very difficult to develop a concrete understanding. It's not so much the questions that we have to keep an eye on, but the answers.

And sometimes the critique can be very technical. [This question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20105/what-is-the-meaning-of-these-photodune-reasons-for-rejection), for instance, dealt with more than just artistic and technical criticism of the image *as a photograph*, but with the technical requirements of stock photography as well (bleed allowances, composing for typical layout crops and so on).

Comment: I would +1, because I do agree that something like the example you gave should be allowed, but the 'particularly' gets me.  **I** don't want to encourage 'general critique' *at all*.

Comment: @rfusca — the alternative scenario I was thinking of was the "I've done everything right... why is it still so wrong" question, not the "like me and my pics on Facebook" sort of thing. Again, it's the difference between theoretical abstractions (book learnin') and art. "Manual" questions are a much bigger turn-off to me; you can pick that stuff up without ever picking up a camera.

Comment: I'm think that'd be fine, so long as they can't point out *at least one thing* that isn't fine to us.  At that point, it essentially becomes what @chills and I are talking about - critique with a focus.  The problem is, so many people think their stuff *isn't* "me and my pics on Facebook" and we need to make sure we're not the ones sorting that out on the main page of the Q&A site.

Answer (score 3):

Totally agree. Looking at a good picture and understanding what can make it better is very helpful. This is not a rate my photo Flickr group :) But yet photos are a great learning tool for photographers :D

Answer (score 2):

Technical critiques should be allowed, definitely, because they are really nothing more than a question with an example attached. Technical could mean something about exposure or focus, or something about following composition rules, for example.

I'd say any subjective critique should not be allowed, which I think basically just comes down to "do you like this?" and "critique my photo" questions.

More than anything, I think it comes down to how the critique/question is asked. "Critique my photo, please" is a bad choice because there's no clear way to answer that correctly. But a better question/request for critique could be helpful and productive: "why doesn't my photo have the impact I imagined? I tried to recreate 'x' and create 'y' mood, but it fell short -- what did I do wrong?" I suspect the resulting discussion would be interesting, cite resources, provide insight, and be very worthwhile. How do we encourage well-written questions?

Comment: But, if we allow that composition rules are [more like guidelines than actual rules](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bplEuBjppTw), doesn't that make all such questions subjective? Where would you draw that line?

Comment: I'd say if the question is explicitly asking about a compositional rule, it's ok. "I'm told this follows the rule of thirds; what does that means?" is a valid question with a clear answer. Anisha's recent question about candles/focus falls into this category. But if it's just fishing with "does this follow any composition rules" it's not a good question.

Comment: I disagree. You're asking about a specific rule/idea: a central point of interest.

Answer (score -1):

Great answers and comments so far.

It's often suggested if you want to improve your photography, you should study the masters (photographs and artwork in general).  Learn to read and interpret art and photographs.  Assisting in that could be very useful and appropriate.

I'd welcome limited and focused critique along the lines of what Stan and Dan said.  Even better, and safer, might be to post up some famous photographs and ask questions about them - why are they so well regarded, is it the composition, the light, the emotion.  Deconstructing (if that's the right word) some of these photos could be interesting and educational.

Comment: @Anisha - not my downvote, but on meta, downvotes just mean "I disagree". (notice that they don't affect reputation)

Comment: @Anisha Kaul:  There's been much discussion on the main meta site around commenting on downvotes.  For me, I wouldn't expect every downvote to get a comment (particularly on meta) in much the same way that I wouldn't expect people to explain their upvotes.  The suggestion that people comment is apparently there now for lower rep users: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes

Comment: @MikeW: I'm not sure about the idea of posting famous photographs (where would we stand on copyright for example) I'm also not sure they lend themselves to searchable questions.  I guess an alternative that might work would be 'why is this photo recognised for it's good composition'... or maybe that would lead to a lot of duplicates...

Comment: I'm opposed to this idea of posting famous photos because it sounds like you're just saying "critique my photo" which won't get any legitimate answer.

Comment: @AnishaKaul: The discussion about downvotes and comments on the main site is [here](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/813/is-it-poor-ettiquette-to-downvote-without-leaving-a-comment), although maybe things are a bit different on Meta. Note that Stack Exchange founder Jeff Atwood weighed in on that, so it's not _just_ a personal opinion.

Comment: @AnishaKaul: also, please don't use the back-quotes for quoting people. That's supposed to be for mono-spaced text for filenames and computer code. For quoting someone, use _italics_ and double-quotes. " Thanks! (This one _is_ just my personal opinion, but it's _also_ the intention of Markdown.)

Comment: Yes, I see the questions I gave as examples might be vague and argumentative.  My point was that Ansel Adams, Henri Cartier-Bresson and Robert Capra must have done something right, compositionally, technically, or other, and their images could serve as good examples. Or Rembrandt or Caravaggio for lighting. No risk of offending them either :)

Comment: *"No risk of offending them either :)"* Good thing, that, since Carravaggio was apparently rather quick with a sword when offended.