# What's your opinion on my photograph?

Tags: discussion

> "What's your opinion on my photograph?"

If this question gets reworded as:

> I intended to make a scene depicting A. That's why I chose to keep B in left corner, and C in the top right.
>   Do I need to add or subtract something here which would help me in depicting A better?

Will this be acceptable here?

Comment: It certainly is a lot better, but I think the mods want chat to be used photo critique.

Comment: Give it a shot, only one way to know for sure :-P

Comment: Hey @Aquarius_Girl! I'm trying to avoid spamming this site with this, but I don't see any other contact information for you. I'm helping launch a new community-owned Q&A site and I hope we can learn from our mistakes and missteps here. I really value many of the composition and thematic design questions you brought to this site early on, and our struggle with how to react to those constructively is a lot of what I want to do better on on the new site. I'd love to have you participate. See https://meta.codidact.com/questions/74831 if you're interested!

Comment: @PleaseReadMyProfile Thank you for the invitation. I would definitely post there when I start again with photography now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe as long as the question is focused it can be acceptable here

The first question is obviously too broad and opinion-based.

The reworded question is still going to be somewhat opinion-based, but it is focused and there are rules of composition that can be applied, so it is probably answerable.  It tells what your intention is, what you've tried, and maybe what it also needs is why you think it falls short of your vision.  For example, "B and C are important for the scene, but I find they distract from A - what technique can I use to help draw the viewer's eye to A".

As long as it's not open-ended, but the question focuses on a single aspect of the image and/or a single technique to improve the image, I think such a question can be allowed here.

See: [photo critiques are allowed, so long as they are about a specific technique](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/815/how-can-we-do-photo-critiques/818#818)