# Can we add some way to semi-automatically add a "please DESCRIBE your desired effect" block to _those_ questions?

Tags: support, feature-request

Questions like

- [How do i give this look to my photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/70700/how-do-i-give-this-look-to-my-photos)
- [How this photograph is taken?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/revisions/70669/1)
- [How to process a photo to get same look?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/revisions/70533/1)
- [What is this effect called and how can I post process my photos to get this effect?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/revisions/25780/1)
- [How is this effect created in Photoshop?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/56879/how-is-this-effect-created-in-photoshop)
- [How to achieve this effect in photoshop?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/57722/how-to-achieve-this-effect-in-photoshop)
- [Is somebody know this post-processing effect?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/revisions/25285/1)
- [Can someone identify this particular photo effect?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/can-someone-identify-this-particular-photo-effect)

are incredibly frustrating to me, because on the one hand these are exactly¹ the kind of thing I want to see more of on the site: how do I achieve a certain look or follow a certain technique, rather than "what brand photowidgets to buy?", but on the other hand, they are:

- indistinguishable,
- unsearchable,
- and usually, almost completely unclear

awhile ago, I wrote a long rant about this — [Important information for asking "What's this effect?" questions](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/important-information-for-asking-whats-this-effect-questions) — and as you've probably noticed I generally drop a link to it when one of these questions come in (with medium-to-fair results).

But I'm tired of doing that. Is there some way we could have this as a template that can be dropped in place with a click or a flag? Maybe it could be a custom close reason, but it's not a custom *off-topic* reason — topicality isn't the problem.

(This is mostly a question for Stack Exchange devs, because.... I don't think there's much even the moderators can do here.)

---

<sub>1. well, minus that some of these examples are subjectively crazy over-baked and tasteless, but, hey, no accounting for taste</sub>

Answer (score 5):

We can try to make this situation better by doing one of two things:

1. We can make it so that a block/prompt appears next to the text box for inputting the question, asking the users to be more specific, and possibly even linking to [your Meta post](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/important-information-for-asking-whats-this-effect-questions).
   This would have to have a trigger, though. This could be a tag (or set of tags), or a set of words. *However*, we should make sure these triggers are actually something that is usually used by users who will post questions with those kinds of titles, *and* rarely used by other users who won't do so. **Can you think of what those triggers might be?**
   The end result would be something similar to [what we did in the Anime site](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2550/49).
2. We can add a link to [your Meta post](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/important-information-for-asking-whats-this-effect-questions) in the sidebar next to the text box for inputting the question, under "how to ask". It could look something like this:
   [image: possible solution]

Comment: Nice! I like the first option. I'll have to think about some triggers.

Comment: The word "this" in combination with "look" or "effect". Possibly also "process".

Comment: Actually, make that "process" or "photoshop".

Comment: Another trigger: Just one or two lines of text plus a photo or link.

Comment: Playing around with Data explorer, I think any of `this [effect|look]` or `[effect|look|photo|photograph|picture] like` or just `like this` is pretty good. There's some false positives, though. (Is there a way to do SEDE searches on original, non-edited posts?)

Comment: You can look for `InitialTitle` and `InitialBody` on `PostHistory`.

Comment: Hmmm. I don't think I can. :)

Comment: Anyway, looking for phrases like a just suggested two comments up isn't adequate — it misses most of my examples.

Comment: I wish we could do this on tags, like your example on Anime, but these are _also_ often tagged poorly too — [tag:photo-editing], [tag:photoshop], [tag:digital-photography]. If we're "lucky", [tag:effect] or [tag:reverse-engineering].

Comment: Check out [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) for some more info. You _should_ be able to see `InitialTitle` and `InitialBody` on `PostHistory`. Are you sure you can't? If you can find no suitable triggers, how does option 2 sound?

Comment: An example of a question that should be flagged: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/97402/photography-editing. In this case, "One or two lines of text plus a link to instagram" would be an effective trigger. It wouldn't have been caught by "this effect|look" because they used the word "editing" in a kind of odd way.

Comment: Another trigger word: *filter*.

Answer (score 2):

Although not ideal, it is better than nothing.

You can copy/paste the following into a comment to an offending question that asks, "How do I get this effect/filter/editing?" To copy/paste with the correct formatting, triple-click the line below to select it all and then copy.

I give you my complete permission to use it however you wish.

```
[Important information for asking “What's this effect?” questions](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3881/15871) and [What's the best way to ask a “How do I achieve this effect?” question?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/677/15871)
```

Posted in a comment, the above lines will appear as:

[Important information for asking “What's this effect?” questions](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3881/15871) and [What's the best way to ask a “How do I achieve this effect?” question?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/677/15871)

Comment: Thanks, Matt!!!

Comment: For active reviewers such as yourself, I highly recommend installing [Tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net) into your browser, which will then let you install userscripts, such as SE's [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) script. Then you can set the above comment text to be inserted with a click into any comment box on Photo.SE.