# Can I ask about how to develop this specific photograph?

Tags: support, questions, asking-questions, specific-question

I am extremely new to this SE site and I have not been on SE for a while in general, so I kind of got out of the SE 'habits'.

I would like to know if questions, typically 'How did they develop this photograph?' are on scope here. To put this into more context, I aim to ask how the author of a specific photograph managed to merge two photographs on black and white film through the use of enlarger. I apologize if this has been asked before, or if questions on the process of this kind already exist. I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, these types of questions are on scope and welcomed here provided one uses a descriptive title and also describes what exact attribute in the image it is that one wishes to understand and/or replicate. Since only text is searchable here, the lack of a good descriptive title and question body makes it difficult for anyone else looking for similar information to find an existing question that only asks "how do I get this effect?"

For more, please see:
[Important information for asking "What's this effect?" questions](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/important-information-for-asking-whats-this-effect-questions)
[What's the best way to ask a "How do I achieve this effect?" question?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/677/whats-the-best-way-to-ask-a-how-do-i-achieve-this-effect-question)

Comment: Thank you so much, I learned a lot through your answer and the links provided.